# How to find the name of the SO file which contains the code for a specific function

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm creating a dotnet core project and would like to call into some linux system functions using P/Invoke.
How do I find which .so file does the desired functionality reside in?

Eg. to use getpid, I need to add this import-

```
[DllImport("libc.so.6")]
```

The netlink connector [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/netlink.3.html) suggests that we only use NLMSG_DATA to parse the data received from the connector, and i'd like to invoke this method from within my c# code. How do I find out which so file to import?

Answer (score 4):

To find out which dynamic libraries export which symbol, on a GNU system, you can try  something like:

```
ldconfig -p |
  sed -n 's/.* => //p' |
  sort -u |
  xargs -d '\n' nm --defined-only -oDg |
  grep -w getpid
```

(in first approximation; that could be improved by removing duplicates at inode level).

Something similar can be done with static libraries or any ELF or other object supported by `nm`, though you may need to adapt the flags, and how to gather the list of files you want to search in.

However here, `NLMSG_DATA` being all uppercase is more likely  to be a C preprocessor macro.

```
$ grep -r NLMSG_DATA /usr/include
/usr/include/linux/netlink.h:#define NLMSG_DATA(nlh)  ((void*)(((char*)nlh) + NLMSG_LENGTH(0)))
```

To look for definitions in C headers, instead of `grep`, you may want to use some code indexing tools like `ctags`, `cscope` or `gtags` and index the whole of `/usr/include`.

You can also get the C  pre-processor to  expand it:

```
printf '%s\n' '#include <linux/netlink.h>' 'please_describe[NLMSG_DATA(nlh)]' |
  gcc -P -E -x c - | sed '/please_describe/,$!d'
please_describe[((void*)(((char*)nlh) + ((0) + ((int) ( ((sizeof(struct nlmsghdr))+4U -1) & ~(4U -1) )))))]
```

So it just returns a pointer some offset off the input pointer based on the size of `struct nlmsghdr` (which you could determine using the C compiler or debugging symbols of some object that uses that `struct`).

Note that headers being not needed to run software, only to  build them, they won't be installed by default for all libraries, so you may need to install some `xxx-dev` or `xxx-devel` packages to bring them in.

When you do have the man page for the library  function (does not really  apply here as it's some kernel API), chances are you also have the header files. You can work your way  from the man page to the package and then to the headers and library. For instance on Debian and derivatives for the `attr_setf` function:

```
$ man -w attr_setf
/usr/share/man/man3/attr_set.3.gz
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/man/man3/attr_set.3.gz
libattr1-dev:amd64: /usr/share/man/man3/attr_set.3.gz
$ dpkg -L libattr1-dev | grep /include/
/usr/include/attr
/usr/include/attr/attributes.h
/usr/include/attr/error_context.h
/usr/include/attr/libattr.h
/usr/include/attr/xattr.h
```

For the libraries, you can guess the package is `libattr1` or use the fact that the `-dev` package will depend on the runtime one:

```
$ apt-cache show libattr1-dev | grep Depends
Depends: libc6-dev | libc-dev, libattr1 (= 1:2.4.47-2build1)
$ dpkg -L libattr1 | grep /lib/
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1.1.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1
$ nm -Dg /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 | grep attr_setf
00000000000016e0 T attr_setf
```

If you do not have the man page, but know it exists, you can look-up which package it's available from:

```
$ apt-file search -x 'man.*/attr_set\.\d'
libattr1-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/attr_set.3.gz
ncurses-doc: /usr/share/man/man3/attr_set.3ncurses.gz
```